# Set OLE Request Timeout from C++

Tags: c++, com, ole

I am instantiating a local COM server using CoCreateInstance.  Sometimes the application providing the server takes a long time to start.  When this happens, Windows pops a dialog box like this:

**Server Busy**

The action cannot be completed because the other program is busy. Choose 'Switch To' to activate the busy program and correct the problem.

[Switch To...] [Retry] [Cancel]

I have found mention of a Visual Basic property on the Application object, OleRequestPendingTimeout, that can be used to control the time before this dialog comes up.  I can't find any good documentation on this or an equivalent that is useful from C++.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577052/com-server-busy-dialog-on-mfc?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using MFC, we used to do stuff like this:

```
// prevent the damned "Server Busy" dialog.
AfxOleGetMessageFilter()->EnableBusyDialog(0);
AfxOleGetMessageFilter()->EnableNotRespondingDialog(0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at `IMessageFilter` and `CoRegisterMessageFilter`.

Comment: This is a good pointer, it turns out MFC does some of the work as demonstrated in John Dibling's answer.

Answer (score 3):

To increase timeout call:

```
AfxOleGetMessageFilter()->SetMessagePendingDelay(nTimeout);
```

See details here [How to prevent the OLE Server Busy dialog box from appearing during a lengthy COM operation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248019)