# COM "Server busy" dialog on MFC

Tags: com

I have an MFC application that pops up a server busy dialog that looks like:

[image: Server busy dialog]

This app calls AfxOleInit().
[KB248019](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248019) explains that I should do
`AfxOleGetMessageFilter()->SetMessagePendingDelay(nTimeout);`
to avoid getting the dialog. It also suggest that i use OleInitialize instead of AfxOleInit to suppress the dialog.

Does this mean if i don't call `AfxOleInit()`, then i won't get the server busy dialog?
I can't really test because without `AfxOleInit()`, `AfxOleGetMessageFilter()` returns `null` pointer so I can't really set it to 1ms and test if it pops up a dialog when it times out.

So my question is, if I don't call `AfxOleInit()` then would I ever get "server busy" dialog?

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger.  Your UI thread should never run code for more than a few seconds and should never block.  Use threads to perform slow operations, keep your UI responsive to user input.  Makes this dialog disappear as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, the call to `AfxOleInit` does pretty the same as [`OleInitialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690134(v=vs.85).aspx) which internally invokes [`CoInitialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It initializes the COM environment, so you may then use OLE automation, rich OLE containers, ActiveX controls and e.t.c. But additionality it installs a message filter which you may then acquire with `AfxOleGetMessageFilter()`. This message filter is dedicate to handle situations, when an OLE request blocks UI for too long.

So if you call `OleInitialize` instead of `AfxOleInit` no message filter will be installed, and thus you will not see the "Server busy" dialog and `AfxOleGetMessageFilter()` will point to `NULL`.

Also as suggested in the article, you may use

```
AfxOleInit()
....
AfxOleGetMessageFilter()->EnableNotRespondingDialog(FALSE);
```

to disable this dialog.

But your best bet would be to **find the underlying problem**.