# Disable "Server Busy" message when calling third party COM object from C#

Tags: c#, com

I'm trying to write some C# code which calls out to a 3rd party COM object, which is loaded out of process. Sometimes this calls takes a long time to return, and hence our client C# code displays the "Server Busy" MessageBox:

[image: Similar to this]

In MFC it was possible to disable this messagebox appearing by initialising COM differently or by installing a message filter and tweeking the timeout delay value, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577052/com-server-busy-dialog-on-mfc)

I know a better solution would be to have the third party object return immediately, and use a callback interface to let us know when the task is complete - but this isn't an option for us at this stage.

Can anyone suggest a way of disabling the COM timeout in C#?

Comment: Couldn't you call the COM component on a separate thread (e.g. using a Task or a BackgroundWorker)? Or does this component need to run on the UI thread?

Comment: It's actually already calling on a separate thread (a standard C# Thread set to use the STA model)

Comment: Ah, sorry - I think I misunderstood the question. I'll get my coat...!

Comment: Find sample code by googling "c# coregistermessagefilter".