# why there is a "server busy" dialog box?

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I have MFC application that sometimes pops up a server busy dilaog .
This app call a c# dll through com.i found some message in [How to prevent the OLE Server Busy dialog box from appearing during a lengthy COM operation](https://support.microsoft.com/zh-cn/help/248019/how-to-prevent-the-ole-server-busy-dialog-box-from-appearing-during-a-lengthy-com-operation)this mean if i don't call AfxOleInit(), then i won't get the server busy dialog.In my app,I call "CoInitialize" to initialize my com  environment.but my application also pops up the dialog.Why? I'd like to know why the dialog pops up because sometimes the dialog pops up sometimes it doesn't and how to avoid this dialog box.

Comment: `CoInitialize()` initializes COM, but not OLE. What OLE things are you doing in your MFC application? Also you ignored all the other instructions that page gave you, including one that tells you how to turn the dialog off entirely...

Comment: What confuses me is that i just initialized COM not OLE,thus there shouldn't be a server busy dialog box.In my app,the main program is provided by third parties and what i developed is invoked  as a plug.Does possibly the main program use OLE?or Dose this dialog box only pop up when the app use OLE?Is there a way to know if the app uses OLE?

Comment: The main program is probably using OLE then. You will have to inspect the program's source code to find out if it does use OLE. If you are a plugin, you should probably respect the wishes of the main program with regards to the OLE message filter; I'm not sure what advice Microsoft has on that...

Comment: Thank you.now the  question  is that  if the sever busy dialog  only pops up when a app uses OLE.I tried to let my COM sever method takes a long time to return back,but the box didn't pop up.it  fustrated me very much.

Comment: I presume this is because OLE is supposed to be user-driven, so the box is there to tell the user that the other program is busy right now. I'm not fully sure, though...

Comment: The link is no longer valid.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282091/set-ole-request-timeout-from-c

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577052/com-server-busy-dialog-on-mfc